# IIS 6 executing html as aspx

Tags: .net, iis-6

Hi is there a way to configure IIS6 to execute .html extensions as if they were .aspx?

Comment: what do you mean? do you have .net code in the html and you want it to execute?

Comment: Hi Victor, I just want to run a module that monitors for particular urls and then does a 301 redirect - I have 5,000 html files to redirect and don't want to hand code them through the IIS interface ;) Answer is below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so in IIS6 you can open the website properties and go to the "Home Dirctory" tab and there is a section called "Application Settings".  Under this section hit the "Configuration" button and here you can adjust the mappings for different extensions.  I copied the isapi DLL path from a previous extension and added a new extension mapping for:

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll

Also it is important to note that if you are trying to map extensions to files that don't exist (eg if you are url rewriting) you have to make sure to uncheck the box that says to verify if the file exists.