# IIS 6, html file/extension, urlrewriting

Tags: asp.net, html, iis, url-rewriting

I use url rewriting on my site (ASP.NET 4.0 / IIS6), instead of aspx I use html. Everything like described here: [IIS 6 executing html as aspx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856365/iis-6-executing-html-as-aspx) . Problem is that when I have any real .html file (html file exists in the site folder) on the site it doesn't open in web-browser. Is it way to resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: "Also it is important to note that if you are trying to map extensions to files that don't exist (eg if you are url rewriting) you have to make sure to uncheck the box that says to verify if the file exists."

Comment: Yes, I did, problem is that when file (html) exists I need to open it in the browser.

Comment: You say it doesn't open in the web browser. Do you mean that it gets downloaded instead, does it not respond at all or do you get a server error (404/500) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom httpmodule like this:

```
public class CheckRealHtmlFile : System.Web.IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
    public void Init(System.Web.HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
    }
    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Web.HttpApplication app = sender as System.Web.HttpApplication;
        if (app != null)
        {
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rHtml = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\.html$", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (rHtml.IsMatch(app.Context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath) && !System.IO.File.Exists(app.Context.Server.MapPath(app.Context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath)))
            {
                //Execute your html -> aspx logic
            }
            else
                return;
        }
        else
            return;
    }
}
```